# Firebase, React, High Order Function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, higher-order-functions

```
import React from "react";

const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);

export default FirebaseContext;
```

This is a HOC and i am first time working with React Content API and this code is giving me a hard time.. plz help
Why does the 
`export const withFirebase = Component => props =>`
structured this way

Comment: Please be specific--what's the actual question?

Comment: why does the export const have Component and props ?

Comment: Because this is what's called HOC (higher-order component). This is not specific to context API.

Comment: @Navish Because it's a component-that-takes-props wrapped by a function (component) that wraps the component you give it. It's just nested functions.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a currying function. HOC takes a component as input. Also, your component expects props, thats where props comes in.

```
function withFirebase(Component){
  //your HOC logic
}

function Component(props){
 //your logic for component
}
```

this is what it looks with normal javascript

```
withFirebase(Component(Props))
```

ES6 equivalent

```
withFirebase = (Component) => (props)
```

Hope this helps.